# Apple Time Machine, Stop Backup Now, and Initial Back up

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, time-machine

I'm using Apple Time Machine on Snow Leopard to backup a MBPro and am approx 2 hours into initial backup (70GB of 335GB). I'd like to 'Stop Backing Up' because I need to go someplace with my laptop. If I stop, will it start in same place? I can see the inProgress file on backup drive.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1176), an initial back up for their Time Capsule product can be resumed, after a somewhat lengthy data integrity check. Time Capsule also uses Time Machine for back up purposes, so I believe that you should see the same results for your situation.